# Does line length affect performance?

Tags: java

I have very long lines using lambda. Also, for example, I combined two loops with a condition into one line. Will such actions affect performance? Not for readability! Only I work with the code, and it reads great for me.

Example 1 (I have longer lines):

```
send = User.getUsers().stream().filter(it -> it.getPlayer().getWorld().equals(loc.getWorld())).filter(it -> it.getPlayer().getLocation().distance(loc) <= this.distance).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Example 2:

```
for(int y = 0; y < this.yP; y++) for(int x = 0; x < this.xP; x++) if(x != y) this.collection.put(new RelativeLocation(x, y), new ImageData(image, x * 128 * 128));
```

Comment: String length refers to the length of an actual `String` instance. What you have here are simply long lines, not long Strings. Which generally do not affect performance as long as what you do in that line is sensible.

Comment: Mistake, I'm talking about the line

Comment: How you format the source code (whether you write everything on one line or split it up into multiple lines) does not have any influence at all on the generated bytecode and the performance of your program.

Comment: I will strongly suggest you wrap lines for each function call in your stream.  It makes it much easier to see what is going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java is a compiled language, and line length is irrelevant to the compiler.
However, it will affect the readability of your code. Longer lines are - generally - less readable, which makes it harder to understand your code, and therefor harder to maintain it.

In other words, don't write code like this.